# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR - post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, heroku

My website is hosted with a hosting provider, I have no SSL certification yet. On the other hand, the Node.js server is on Heroku. When I want to use the contact form on my website, it gives me this error: **net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR**

Is this because my website has no SSL yet and the Heroku link is **https**? (I can't change this link, otherwise it's 404 not found)

```
app.post('https://myserver.herokuapp.com:80/api/contact', contact);
```

If yes, what do I need to do? Get an SSL certificate for my website that is hosted with another provider? That should solve my issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure **port 80** is correct for HTTPS here …?

Comment: _“Is this because my website has no SSL yet and the Heroku link is https?”_ - no, unlikely. Browsers usually only restrict the other direction, when you try to send any data from a secure to an insecure URL.

Comment: `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;` I thought 80 should be the right one to use.

Comment: The default port for HTTPS is 443.

Comment: Let me try 443, I hope that will work

Comment: Now I get a 404 not found

Comment: Can you call `https://myserver.herokuapp.com:80/api/contact` directly in your browser? I would assume not, and that would mean you have not set things up correctly on the heroku end to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain. There is a contact form on the site to send a message. With port 80, it gave me the SSL error, with port 443, it gives me 404 not found. And for your question, I can open the heroku app with 443, and with 80 cannot (currently the code has port 443)

Comment: So you essentially _never_ had this URL working correctly so far then? Then you need to go and figure out what is wrong with your heroku app setup first of all.

Comment: The heroku app is working. This the code now: `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;` With :80 (on the heroku app) it doesn't open the site and says "This site can’t provide a secure connection". With :443 it's all good and working. However, on my website, the contact form gives me the SSL error with port 80, and not found with port 443.